# Sending attachments via Exchange Web Services API

Tags: perl, soap, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ntlm

I'm currently working on integrating our system with MS Exchange (I'm using Microsoft Exchange Server 2013 15.00.1395.000) and I'm having a weird issue. Namely, I can create email draft and I can send it (as well as call other services), but for some reason I cannot add an attachment to email, because server won't authorize me (I keep getting `401 Anonymous Request Disallowed`).
All calls are made by user with `ApplicationImpersonation` role and here is my Perl function that prepares my calls:

```perl
sub do_authorized_call($$$) {
    my ($callparam1, $callparam2, $callparam3) = @_;
    my $username = 'USERNAME';
    my $password = 'PASSWORD';
    my $proxy = 'exchange.asmx PATH';

    my @ua_args = (keep_alive => 1);
    my @credentials = ("SERVER ADDRESS WITH 443 PORT", "", $username, $password);
    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(@ua_args);
    $ua->credentials(@credentials);

    my $soap = SOAP::Lite
        ->uri(MESSAGES_URI)
        ->ns(MESSAGES_URI, 'm')
        ->endpoint($proxy)
        ->encodingStyle('') # .NET requirement
        ->on_action( sub { join '/', MESSAGES_URI } )
        ->proxy($proxy, @ua_args, credentials => \@credentials)
        ->on_fault(\&soapGetBad);
    $soap->serializer()->register_ns(TYPES_URI, 't');
    $soap->schema->useragent($ua);
    $soap->transport()->proxy->conn_cache($ua->conn_cache);
    return $soap->call($callparam1, $callparam2, $callparam3);
```

CreateAttachment request generated by this function look as follows:

```
POST <EWS ADDRESS> HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/xml
Accept: multipart/*
Accept: application/soap
Authorization: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAB7IAAAoACgAgAAAAAgACACoAAABBcHBJbXBfU1ZDQ1c=
User-Agent: SOAP::Lite/Perl/1.27
Content-Length: 52759
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
                <t:SmtpAddress>USER_EMAIL</t:SmtpAddress>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
        </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <CreateAttachment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <ParentItemId ChangeKey="CQAAABYAAABp6uewA08qSL/Bt1DTe9bxAAAS2C7L" Id="AAMkAGM5N2Q4MGU2LTNlYTMtNDIzZi1iZTg4LTFlZmRmZTQ1NTQ4MQBGAAAAAADa5apTmZVLS4pW4o+BzNotBwBp6uewA08qSL/Bt1DTe9bxAAAAAAEPAABp6uewA08qSL/Bt1DTe9bxAAAS2C56AAA=" />
            <Attachments>
                <t:FileAttachment>
                    <t:Name>Attachment555.docx</t:Name>
                    <t:Content>ATTACHMENT CONTENT REMOVED FOR BREVITY</t:Content>
                </t:FileAttachment>
            </Attachments>
        </CreateAttachment>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If I send exactly same envelope in SoapUI and provide username and password as NTLM authorization, it all works properly.

And again, as I said in the beginning, I have 3 requests in sequence: create draft, add attachments (if needed) and send draft (all using the same `do_authorized_call` that has uses the same credentials. If I comment the attachments out, draft creation and sending works perfectly fine, no issue with authorization. But as soon as attachments are involved, it all fails. I checked logs and couldn't figure anything out. All I read is several failed authorization attempts.

I'm feeling helpless right now, because I browsed the internet far and wide, I've checked everything, debugged it hundred times, verifying every single line of code and can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: There are not a lot of resources on non-Microsoft language implementations for the Exchange web services. Especially not on Perl. I've gotten everything I needed working using and extending https://metacpan.org/pod/EWS::Client locally. But it doesn't have built in what you need, I believe.

Comment: To make your debugging easier, take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger, especially LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere, which I submitted to LWP::ConsoleLogger  when I was debugging the EWS API.

Comment: @simbabque How is it different to `SOAP::Lite +trace => "all"` which already gives me full envelope and request headers?

Comment: There's probably not a big difference. It handles requests and responses. However, the implementation for the webservice I used was based on XML::Compile::SOAP, not SOAP::Lite, so didn't provide easy extra debugging options.

Comment: Do you get the same auth error with incorrect password? Is it the same for all 3 requests? Maybe there are additional requirements to add an attachment. Are you sure that you try to add an attachment to the right draft?

Comment: Did you try to add “ <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline> <t:IsContactPhoto>false</t:IsContactPhoto> ”, like this: ”
<t:Attachments>
            <t:FileAttachment>
              <t:Name>FileAttachment.txt</t:Name>
              <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline>
              <t:IsContactPhoto>false</t:IsContactPhoto>
              <t:Content>VGhpcyBpcyBhIGZpbGUgYXR0YWNobWVudC4=</t:Content> </t:FileAttachment></t:Attachments>
”. 
Please refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-add-attachments-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: I finally came to conclusion that problem was that attachment was too big (although it was around 40KB, which is strange). When I sent smaller file, it worked just fined. Question however remains why it worked with SOAP UI, but not in code?